# Don't execute foreach loop if array is empty

Tags: magento-1, orders, array

I have the following code, if there are **no orders older then** **`$days_ago`**, I want that the **`foreach`** loop won't be executed. I don't know how to do this.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lt' => $days_ago));

     foreach ($orders as $order):
        if(!$this->_shouldBeAnonymised($order)):
            continue;
     endif;

        $this->_anonymiseSale($order);
     endforeach;
```

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

except `getSize()` you can use count as well,

like below

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lt' => $days_ago));

if($orders->count() > 0):
    foreach ($orders as $order):
        if(!$this->_shouldBeAnonymised($order)):
            continue;
        endif;

        $this->_anonymiseSale($order);
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lt' => $days_ago));
    if ($orders->getSize()) {
        foreach ($orders as $order):
            if(!$this->_shouldBeAnonymised($order)):
                continue;
            endif;

            $this->_anonymiseSale($order);
        endforeach;
    }
```